# How to store ASCII information in Bitmap header?

Tags: c#, metadata, bmp

I see there is an area in the bitmap header to store additional information. So if I were to write an image in C#, would it be possible for me to add extra ASCII information in the header?

```
public void writeToPath(GMapControl form)
{
    if(path == String.Empty || path == null)
        path=Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);

    int width = form.Size.Width;
    int height = form.Size.Height;

    Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(width, height);
    form.DrawToBitmap(bm, new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height));

    bm.Save("C:\SomePath\blah");

}
```

[image]

Comment: Where in this specification do you see a field for "Additional information"? And it's very likely that you will not be able to do what you want using the `Bitmap` class, as I'm sure that was not intended for byte-by-byte editing of a bitmap file. Instead, you'll likely need to open the bitmap file and manipulate it directly.

And might I ask *why* you want to insert data into the header of a bitmap? It sounds like whatever you're trying to achieve could be better implemented using some other solution.

Comment: @SpikeX Please see the page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format. What would be the 'better' solution. I would like to create a bitmap that my applicatin alone knows it created it. That way i can rescan a directory full of pictures to know that my app made it  so i can scan in only those pictures

Comment: Okay, and where, specifically, are you looking to insert data? What byte offset? How much data?

Comment: just a little uuid somewhere, any where possible. something that I can identify my bitmaps that my app created. I think at 0006h (2bytes) that will work

Comment: Okay, so in the actual file, at offsets `0x0006` and `0x0008`, you get two bytes each to put in whatever you want. Open your file as a byte[] and edit those particular bytes in the file after it's been saved.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755185/how-to-add-comments-to-a-jpeg-file-using-c-sharp ? The API should be the same for both, I believe.

Comment: I may be 'off' - but have you considered just 'naming' files in a way that could give you a clue that it belongs to you? Unless your files will 'migrate' and could be editing using other apps etc.

Comment: @NSGaga Nah. that wont be sufficient for my needs. The end user is free to do whatever he/she wants to the image after its spit out.

Comment: I thought so. Anyway, Bitmap format doesn't support any metadata (not officially) - I'd take a look at `steganography` and it might be easier way out. e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/397537/adding-an-invisible-image-watermark-in-c

Comment: You are actually saving the image in the PNG format, not the BMP format.  Good choice, it supports [metadata](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8113314/does-png-support-metadata-fields-like-author-camera-model-etc)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the easiest way to go about this without delving into the business of `BITMAPINFOHEADER` is to simply open the file again and edit the particular bytes you are after.

Here's some (untested) code:

```
using (var stream = File.Open(@"C:\SomePath\blah.jpg", FileMode.Open))
{
    var myBytes = new byte[] { /* put up to 4 bytes here */ };

    stream.Position = 6; //there is some space at 0x006 and 0x0008 for your data
    stream.Write(myBytes, 0, myBytes.Length);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the *file offset to pixel array* by the size of your meta data. Then you put your data just before the pixel array. However, you need to have your own bmp io routines to write and retrieve the extra data chunk.