# Adding an invisible watermarks to SVG in C#?

Tags: c#, hidden, watermark, computer-forensics

I found this discussion about images: [Adding an invisible image watermark in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/397537/adding-an-invisible-image-watermark-in-c)

And I've found some good open source libraries for watermarking raster images.
One example: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Grizlah.Steganography.F5.StegSharp.Infrastructure

My interest is in watermarking SVG images. I know that different algorithms would be involved with vector.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a library to manipulate svg, just add a similar group like that into the svg. Your could calculate the repition of the use elements by the width and height of the svg.

you can use [svg dotnet nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Svg/) to do this.

```
 var sampleDoc = SvgDocument.Open<SvgDocument>("filePath")
 var waterMarkDoc = SvgDocument.FromSvg<SvgDocument>("<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' height='500px' width='500px' >
      <g>
        <text id="mark" transform="rotate(-45)" fill='rgba(45,45,45,0.3)' font-size='18'>
        watermark
        </text>
        <use href="#mark" x="100" y = "100"/>
        <use href="#mark" x="200" y = "100"/>
        <use href="#mark" x="300" y = "100"/>
        <use href="#mark" x="100" y = "200"/>
        <use href="#mark" x="200" y = "200"/>
        <use href="#mark" x="300" y = "200"/>
      </g>
 </svg>")
  foreach(var element in watermark.Children){
     sampleDoc.Children.Add(element);
  }


 sampleDoc.Draw().Save("filename.png"));
```

[image: output]